# How to wire USB 2.0 to 5-pin CAN

Tags: usb, wire, cables, can, adapter

I Need to connect a USB-cable with a CAN-cable.
USB has 4 Pins: VBUS, D-, D+ and GND.
CAN has 5 Pins: CAN_SHLD, CAN_V+, CAN_GND, CAN_H, CAN_L.
Which wire goes where?

edit: I already have a USB-to-CAN-Stick from miControl, but the cable to connect the USB Stick with the 5-pin CAN-Interface went missing.

Comment: If you are planning to talk to your CAN bus via USB, this is not  how things work...

Comment: If you have the CAN USB converter then including the make, model and a link to the datasheet would probably help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a fundamental misunderstanding, or it lacks any mention of the central piece of this question (a specific USB/CAN converter device)

Answer (score 2):

USB and CAN use different signal levels, different protocols, different timing, different everything. You cannot connect them together directly.

Answer (score 2):

You do not connect USB wiring directly to the CAN bus. The miCAN-Stick2 acts as an interface between the two. The stick plugs into a USB socket and the CAN bus connects to the 5 pin connector on the back of the stick. The pin assignement is shown below. Oddly they have described the cable as "USB cable" but you should ignore that.

[image]

Comment: You're right, so I need to connect this cable to the CAN cable from P+F: [link](http://www.pepperl-fuchs.com/global/en/classid_255.htm?&view=productdetails&prodid=23263) I connected 2 with 2, 3 with 3 and 5 with 5, but it's still not working

Answer (score 1):

You can't just connect USB to CAN.  It doesn't work that way.

You need some kind of "converter" or "adapter".  You also need software at least on one end that presents actions on the remote bus locally.